# MDX " FILTER " condition not working

Tags: mdx, pentaho

Now my problem is Filter condition in MDX query.The MDX query used by me is shown below

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total],
            [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { [Offer].[Grand Total],
            [Offer].[Grand Total].Children } ON ROWS 
FROM
  [SCMAircelCube]
WHERE
( [Measures].[TotalCount], 
  [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully] ,
  [SubscriberProfile].[Active], 
  [Circle].[ASSAM])
```

Problem with this query is ,this is showing offers starting with ''AOL" .Actually i dont want to show that offer in the report.So i am trying to use the FILTER condition.But it is not working too.I am getting error.Can anyone help me 
i want to use filter condition on ROWS.I used the following MDX for filtering.But error is getting

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total],
            [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS,
FILTER( { [Offer].[Grand Total],
          [Offer].[Grand Total].Children !=[AOL]} ) ON ROWS
FROM
  [SCMAircelCube]
WHERE
( [Measures].[TotalCount], 
  [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully] , 
  [SubscriberProfile].[Active], 
  [Circle].[ASSAM])
```

Thanks and Regards
plshelpmep

Answer (score 0):

Is your [filter mdx function](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/Filter.html) which is most probably causing the issue, can you try with something like :

```
FILTER( { [Offer].[Grand Total],[Offer].[Grand Total].Children}, 
        [Offer].[Grand Total].currentmember is not [Offer].[Grand Total].[AOL] )
```

As an answer to you comment and fixing brackets issues :

```
SELECT 
 { [Channel].[Grand Total], [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS, 
 FILTER ( {[Offer].[Grand Total], [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, 
   not([Offer].[Grand Total].currentmember is [Offer].[Grand Total].[AJOKED]) ) ON ROWS
FROM [SCMAircelCube] 
WHERE ( [Measures].[TotalCount], [Time].[2012].[1], [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully], [ContentCategory].[SMS], [SubscriberProfile].[Active], [Circle].[KARNATAKA])
```

Comment: Hi..,    I changed my MDX query to the following format with the above 'FILTER'  condition like  yours..BUt now again i am getting error like    "Query Execution Failed"An exception was encountered while executing the query like that.. 
 Any Idea...

Comment: The MDX Qry used by me is.. SELECT { [Channel].[Grand Total], [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS, FILTER ( { [Offer].[Grand Total], 
 [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].currentmember is not [[Offer].[Grand Total].AJOKED]}) ON ROWS
 FROM [SCMAircelCube] WHERE 
 ( [Measures].[TotalCount], Time].[2012].[1], [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully], 
 [ContentCategory].[SMS], [SubscriberProfile].[Active], [Circle].[KARNATAKA])

Comment: I fixed some brackets issues and change the 'is not' to a 'not' and 'is'. Can you try now ? ... if no remove the where clause, after this filter (the whole on ROWS line), use {[Offer].[Grand Total], [Offer].[Grand Total].Children } ON ROWS... to check what is wrong

Comment: Hi..!!!,  Thank you very much. Now It is working fine..Now i am trying to filter more than one offernames by using the same Query..?  Is it possible to do with "not and is" close  ?

Comment: I tried this query..SELECT 

NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total], [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS, 
{ [Offer].[Grand Total], EXCEPT ( { [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].[AJOKED] }), EXCEPT ( { [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].[ Airauto] }) } ON ROWS FROM 
[SCMAircelCube] 
WHERE 
( [Measures].[TotalCount], [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully], [SubscriberProfile].[Active], [Circle].[ASSAM])   But only first "EXCEPT" condition is working.ie, offername 'AJOKED' is filtered but 'Airauto' not..

Comment: hi ,  Then u can try like this
  SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total], [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS, 
{ [Offer].[Grand Total], 
Except ( { [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].[Action Gaming], 
[Offer].[Grand Total].[Actor & Actresses] }) } ON ROWS FROM 
[SCMAircelCube] 
WHERE 
( [Measures].[TotalCount])

Answer (score 0):

You could use the EXCEPT function:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total],
            [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS,
 { [Offer].[Grand Total], EXCEPT({[Offer].[Grand Total].Children}, {[Offer].[Grand Total].[AOL]})}  ON ROWS
FROM
  [SCMAircelCube]
WHERE
( [Measures].[TotalCount], 
  [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully] , 
  [SubscriberProfile].[Active], 
  [Circle].[ASSAM])
```

Comment: Hi..!!!,  Thank you very much. Now It is working fine..Now i am trying to filter more than one offernames by using the same Query..?  Is it possible with the 'EXCEPT' CONDITION..?

Comment: Hi..,   I tried this query..                                    SELECT 
NON EMPTY { [Channel].[Grand Total], [Channel].[Grand Total].Children } ON COLUMNS, 
{ [Offer].[Grand Total], EXCEPT ( { [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].[AJOKED] }), EXCEPT ( { [Offer].[Grand Total].Children }, { [Offer].[Grand Total].[ Airauto] }) } ON ROWS FROM 
[SCMAircelCube] 
WHERE 
( [Measures].[TotalCount], [BasicCause].[Subscriber activated successfully], [Circle].[ASSAM])   But only first "EXCEPT" condition is working.ie, offername 'AJOKED' is filtered but 'Airauto' not..

Comment: Use this:
Except({[Offer].[Grand Total].Children}, {[Offer].[Grand Total].[AJOKED], [Offer].[Grand Total].[ Airauto]})

Comment: Hi..,  Thanks again...It is working fine..That problem also solved..             Thanks and Regards                                                                     user969084